# CGI program run in debug mode

Tags: c++, apache, gdb

We have a C++ CGI application which serves some web request. I am trying to run the same in debug mode for analysis purpose. The approach I have taken is invoking it with gdb:

As per first step  -  I rename my actual CGI application and place my own program with the same name

In that program I am trying to invoke the actual CCGI application in debug mode using GDB:

```
const char* argv[] = ["gdb -p <pid> -batch -ex bt 2>/dev/null", NULL];

execve("./myprog", (char**)argv, NULL);
```

The issue is that since myrog is a CGI application it takes input from STDIN.

How can I capture the input in my program and pass the same to the actual CGI application?

Comment: i cannot understand your problem statement.

Comment: Capture (`tcpdump` etc.) or write out the HTTP request, then execute your program manually under `gdb`. Syntax for input redirection is `run < input`, i.e. if you have http_request.dump you would: 1. `gdb ./myprog` 2. `(gdb) run < http_request.dump`

Comment: Thanks . I am able to capture data in my program coming thru stdin via fread system call on stdin file handler - but how do I write it as data to stdin for the actual program that I am invoking progrmatically?

Comment: @zzk : CGI applications are invoke by inetd services with input data passed as in STDIN file handler and outputs to STDOUT file handler. So my requirement is that my application which is a CGI app should capture request from STDIN file and invoke another CGI application by passing the data captured

Comment: Is there a reason you're unable to run the process manually from the command line? Your solution to debugging this application seems needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this:
in cgi main i added code to look for an existing file, like /var/tmp/flag.
While existing, i run in a loop.
Time enough to attach to cgi process via gdb.
After then i delete /var/tmp/flag and from now I can debug my cgi code.

```
bool file_exists(const char *filename)
{
   ifstream ifile(filename);
   return ifile;
}

int cgiMain()
{

 while (file_exists ("/var/tmp/flag"))
     sleep (1);
 ...
 your code
```